# fill text area geckofx [VB.NET]

Tags: html, vb.net, geckofx

I'm trying to fill out a textarea on a web browser (`geckofx v29`) with:

```
Dim wordbox As GeckoInputElement = DirectCast(geckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Note"), GeckoInputElement)

wordbox.InnerHtml = "test"
```

But its not working,

Here is the HTML:

```
<textarea ng-model="MassOrder.MassLinks" class="area mass-tarea ng-valid ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 1000 }" cols="20" id="Note" name="Note" rows="5"></textarea>
```

Anyone any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't change the `InnerHtml`, you need to change the `Value` of that element.

```
 wordbox.Value = "test"
```

Comment: i get an error :System.Invalid.cast.exception, Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'Gecko.DOM.GeckoTextAreaElement' to type 'Gecko.DOM.GeckoInputElement'.

Comment: Welcome, different versions of Gecko are important as the underlying methods and functions do change, thank you for posting what version you are using. Why don't you use the newer version if you don't mind.

Comment: You need to cast to GeckoTextAreaElement